# Count each character in a string

Tags: c#

I have to count character in a string and i'm a little stuck. If input data is "test", the result will be t=2; e=1; s=1; and so on.In my code, the result is t=1; e=1; s=1; and i don't know how to make to work correctly.

```
Input data
```

test

```
Output data   
t=2
e=1
s=1
```

Here is my code

```
public static void Main()
{
    string text = Console.ReadLine();
    string distinctChars = GetDistinctChars(text);
    foreach (char c in distinctChars)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c + " " + CountCharOccurrences(distinctChars, c));
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

}
private static int CountCharOccurrences(string text, char charToCount)
{
    int count = 0;

    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if (c == charToCount)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

private static string GetDistinctChars(string text)
{
    string result = "";
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        if (result.IndexOf(c) == -1)
        {
            result += c;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Consider using a dictionary to track and keep counts.

Comment: increment the dictionary in this method?"CountCharOccurrences"

Comment: You are calculating the counts on the distinct chars - of course you get 1

Comment: @gunr2171 not really

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
       Console.WriteLine(c + " " + CountCharOccurrences(distinctChars, c));
```

should be

```
       Console.WriteLine(c + " " + CountCharOccurrences(text , c));
```

There are better ways to do this than how you are doing it.  Using a Dictionary object is probably the best.  Then you only need to loop over the original text once.

Comment: "better ways to do this" they probably haven't learnt about dictionaries yet. IMHO this is a nice algorithmic solution to this problem

Comment: @MongZhu -- exactly why I put it the way I did -- something to look forward to learning about on the journey